# Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have one input parameter `categoryid`.

I want to create a stored procedure for `categoryfetch` with this input parameter. I have a table `category` with columns `categoryid`, `shopid`, `title`, `logicalcode`.

Can any one tell the stored procedure for category fetch with one input parameter?

Comment: Is this homework? See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx

Comment: This isn't even a query, just a blatant "do my work for me" request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create procedure categoryfetch 
    @categoryid int
as
    select categoryid, shopid, title, logicalcode 
    from category 
    where categoryid = @categoryid
go
```

Answer (score 0):

create procedure categoryfetch 
 @categoryid int
as
 select shopid,title,logicalcode
 from category where categoryid=@categoryid end

for execute it

exec categoryfetch @categoryid=categoryid