# sql stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have table called "`product review`" with columns `productreviewid` , `productid` ,`shopperid`, `review` , `rating` .
I want to create the stored procedure for `productreviewfetch`  with input parameter `productreview ID`

Can Any one pls help me out ?

Comment: output is "bool" type can any one pls help me

Comment: Can't you apply what you learned from the answer to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408326/stored-procedure

Comment: Is this homework?  (There is a homework tag.)  What have you tried?

Comment: A typical homework question !

Comment: All your questions over the past 4 days are about 'stored procedures'.  Maybe you should include your instructor in some of this repartee.

Comment: Why the question is not closed yet ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not very clear about what you're trying to do - but something like this might get you started:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.FetchReviews @ProductReviewID INT
AS
   SELECT 
       ProductReviewID, ProductID, ShopperID, Review, Rating
   FROM
       dbo.ProductReview
   WHERE
       ProductReviewID = @ProductReviewID
```

Does that give you the expected results??

It will return the values for those five columns, if your `ProductViewID` exists, and all NULL values, if that ID is not in your table.

Comment: @ProductReviewID should be typed

Comment: @Stuart Dunkeld: good catch! Just guessing - but might be what the OP has in mind..

Comment: A nice solution ... But will have to check with OP.

Comment: ya that is absolutely correct thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft SQL Server provides the stored procedure mechanism to simplify the database development process by grouping Transact-SQL statements into manageable blocks.

More here : [SQL Stored Procedures](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/SQL-Server/SQL-Server-Stored-Procedures-101/)

Comment: Yes I deleted my comment as RTFM might well be an appropriate answer here!